# Bootstrap - padding in span makes it bigger

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, padding

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="cover" class="span12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="first_left" class="span6 left">
            <h3>aa</h3>

        </div>
        <div id="first_right" class="span5">
            ee
        </div>
    </div>
```

And less:

```
#cover{
    background: url('couv.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 960px;
    height: 280px;
}

h3{
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #FFF;
}

.left{
    background: url('grille.jpg');
    padding: 15px;
}
```

The "first_right" span displays below first_left, and only if the 15px padding is present. With padding 15, first_left becomes 490px wide instead of 460px. Why is that ?
Also, is it ok to have padding on a span if I want to nest some more rows in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`. This does not include `padding`. The `padding` extends the width (if set) of the element. You need to set `border-box` to include the `padding` and `borders` in the element width.

```
.left{
    background: url('grille.jpg');
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now the width includes padding and borders.

[Read more about box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thank you. But why fix the div width ? it seems like box sizing alone does the job

Comment: I thought you want it to be exactly 460px wide. My fault :-)